# EXCEL: Single column data into multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, powerquery

I have a below thing to replicate the rows into multiple rows where the fields are separated with comma.

| SCRIPTNM | TABLE NAME |
| --- | --- |
| `scriptA.ksh` | DB.TABLE1, DB.TABLE2 |
| `scriptA.exp` | DB.TABLE4 |

to replace as below:

| SCRIPTNM | TABLE NAME |
| --- | --- |
| `scriptA.ksh` | DB.TABLE2 |
| `scriptA.ksh` | DB.TABLE2 |
| `scriptA.exp` | DB.TABLE4 |

I can try to split the rows to columns using comma delimiter, but the below rows should not effect.

**Updated relistic input:**

| SCRIPTNM | TABLE NAME |
| --- | --- |
| `scriptA.ksh` |  |
| `scriptB.ksh` | DB.TABLE2 |
| `scriptC.exp` | DB.TABLE3 |
| `scriptD.exp` | DB.TABLE4,DB.TABLE5 |
| `scriptE.exp` |  |
| `scriptF.exp` | DB.TABLE9 |
| `scriptG.exp` | DB.TABLE10,DB.TABLE11,DB.TABLE13 |
| `scriptH.exp` | DB.TABLE20,DB.TABLE21,DB.TABLE23,DB.TABLE34 |

Comment: This would be most efficiently approached with [PowerQuery](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=39379)

Comment: Yes second that ^^^ [Power Query](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/unpivot-data-with-delimeters-in-power-query-57f57a3ddb4f) will be more efficient approach as mentioned above.

Comment: As suggested by Spetral Instance, PowerQuery makes it rather simple to transform comma separated list into different columns for the whole table. Then “unpivot” 1st table to the 2nd table is also supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/unpivot-column

Comment: @Anonymous No need to unpivot. PQ can split the delimited string in column 2 into rows (instead of columns)

Comment: @Ron Yes, you right: PQ can split to rows directly. Thanks!

Comment: @Ron, how to connect to Power Query from excel2016 ??

Comment: So there are duplicates in the SCRIPTNM column now? scriptF.exp appears twice.

Comment: In 2016, I believe it is on the `Data` Tab --> `Get and Transform Data`

Comment: @Rocky1989 go for Power Query, its much better than any other approaches, no hard coding and no complex formulas to deal with with some simple steps for a query like yours you can achieve it. Just transform the data into a table and load into PQ, PQ editor opens next select the Table Name column and Split By Delimiter by columns instead of rows next select the SCRIPTNM column and right click unpivot other columns this will be dynamic dont just split by rows.

Comment: @Rocky1989 i missed out one vital point here, you need to group the data first in PQ, and join using a delimiter and then follow the steps as mentioned above. if you prefer PQ, then add the tag Power Query in your post then we can share the solution with PQ as well

Answer (score 1):

Formula-based solution for `Excel 2010`, as tagged:

Assuming:

1. Data in `A1:B3` (with headers in row 1)
2. The range `B2:B3` does not contain any empty cells

This **array formula** in `F2`:

`=IF(ROWS(B$2:B2)>SUM(1+LEN(B$2:B$3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B$2:B$3,",",""))),"",INDEX(A$2:A$3,IFERROR(1+MATCH(ROWS(B$2:B2)-1/2,MMULT(N(ROW(B$2:B$3)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B$2:B$3))),1+LEN(B$2:B$3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B$2:B$3,",","")))),1)))`

Copy down until you start to get blanks for the results.

Non-array formula in `F2`:

`=IF(F2="","",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(B$2:B$3,MATCH(F2,A$2:A$3,0)),",",REPT(" ",99)),99*(COUNTIF(F$2:F2,F2)-1)+1,99)))`

Copied down as required.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you please update any screenshot, since we have many rows and the comma separated tables varies in and off (1 table name, blank, 10 table names). Tried the formula but after two rows rest all comes with blank values.

Comment: You need to provide a more realistic example dataset.

Comment: updated the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range` or `From within sheet`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

***M Code***

```
let

//change next line to reflect the actual table name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table9"]}[Content],

//set data type to text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"SCRIPTNM", type text}, {"TABLE NAME", type text}}),

//remove the empty "TABLE NAME" rows
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([TABLE NAME] <> null)),

//Split TABLE NAME column by the comma into rows
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Filtered Rows", {{"TABLE NAME", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "TABLE NAME")
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Formula based alternative solutions, (Array Formulas needs to be keyed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`)

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `D2` --> To Get **SCRIPTNM**

```
=IFERROR(IF(ROW(A1)=1,A2,
IF(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,D1)+1>SUMPRODUCT((MID(
VLOOKUP(D1,$A$2:$B$3,2,),ROW($1:$104),1)=",")*1)+1,
INDEX($A$2:$A$3,MATCH(D1,$A$2:$A$3,)+1),D1))&"","")
```

• Formula used in cell `E2` --> To Get **TABLE NAME**

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(
VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$3,2,),",",REPT(" ",100)),
(COUNTIF($D$1:D2,D2)-1)*100+1,100)),"")
```

---

Or, One more way,

• Formula used in cell `G2` --> To Get **SCRIPTNM**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$3,MATCH(TRUE,COUNTIF(G$1:G1,$A$2:$A$3)<
(LEN($B$2:$B$3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$3,",",""))+1),0)),"")
```

• Formula used in cell `H2` --> To Get **TABLE NAME**

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(
VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$B$3,2,0)&", ",", ",REPT(" ",100)),
COUNTIF($G$2:G2,G2)*100-99,100)),"")
```

---

Comment: Thank you. tried the first formulas, but if the comma separated values are more that 3 or 4, then the split is not happening properly. Do we have to change the REPT function length ?

Comment: @Rocky1989 yeah definitely you need to increase perhaps using Power Query will be more succinct and efficient here