# Get Excel to spit out cell contents with commas (lists) on multiple lines while repeating the rest of that row's data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

We have a database opened through a software that is a list of products with multiple pieces of information per cell (a list separated by commas). You can simply export a product list as is, or you can have it spit out the data by a specific field, which means that the contents of that field will be listed separately in each row, with the product being repeated.

For example, if a Product A has four different items listed in the field displayed in Column X, Product A will then be listed four different times, with all of the data being identical except for Column X, will have each one of those items listed separately on each of the four rows. The software stopped working and it's going to be a little while before they fix it, but I need to pull this report quickly. It's not something I can do manually because there are thousands of products in the database.

Here's an example:

[image]

So I'd want the first product (ABC123) listed three times, with the content in Column D ('Ingredients') being 'mystery meat' in the first row, 'vegetable oil' in the second row, and 'water' in the third row--without the ' of course, and no space or comma at the end of each word or phrase (the space between the words 'mystery' and 'meat,' of course, would be left there). How can I do this? I have the original product list where all of the information is on the same line.

I have no idea how to get Excel to take information and spit it out on multiple lines. There's text-to-columns, which would get me that information in a bunch of different columns, but I don't know how to make Excel then repeat the information in that row the number of times (the number of columns in which there's text). I could use a formula to count the number of items in each cell (the number of columns that have text in them), but I don't know how to make Excel repeat the information in the row that number of times.

Comment: Maybe this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72831536/excel-single-column-data-into-multiple-rows) can help

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to accomplish this task here is two ways using `Modern Excel Functions` aka `MS365` :

[image]

---

```
=REDUCE(A1:D1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:D5)),LAMBDA(φ,δ,VSTACK(φ,IF({1,1,1,0},INDEX(A2:D5,δ,0),TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(A2:D5,δ,4),,", ",1)))))
```

---

Or, without using `LAMBDA()` helper functions:

```
=LET(
     α, A2:D5,
     φ, TAKE(α,,-1),
     δ, MAX(LEN(φ)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(φ,",",))+1),
     Ψ, TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&φ,",",SEQUENCE(,δ)),", ")),
     ε, HSTACK(INDEX(TAKE(α,,3),INT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)*δ,,,1/δ)),SEQUENCE(,3)),TOCOL(Ψ)),
     FILTER(ε,1-ISERROR(TAKE(ε,,-1))))
```

---

Or, *There are many ways to work on this, but in terms of **flexibility**, I would use `POWER QUERY` here which can **effortlessly** do the automation thus saving **time and effort**. `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`*. Watch the demonstration for reference. Takes less then **2 minutes** to perform the task.

[image]

---

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Ingredients", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Ingredients"),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Ingredients", Text.Trim, type text}})
in
    #"Trimmed Text"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

**Note:** *Quite a large amount of datasets can be handled using `POWER QUERY` without any hassle, this is only a one time approach, i.e. you don't have to increase the range nor you have to write the m-codes every single time a new data is added, only you need to refresh the imported table. As far i see this is the most hassle free and time saving tool.*

---

Answer (score 1):

### Transform Data: Split to Rows

```
=LET(data,A1:E8,split_col,4,has_headers,1,dlm,", ",
    cd,IF(data="","",data),
    d,IF(has_headers,DROP(cd,1),cd),
    sc,CHOOSECOLS(d,split_col),
    ms,SEQUENCE(,MAX((LEN(sc)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(sc,dlm,)))/LEN(dlm)+1)),
    sd,TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(dlm&sc,dlm,ms),dlm)),
    od,CHOOSEROWS(d,TOCOL(IF(ms,SEQUENCE(ROWS(d))))),
    so,IF(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(d))=split_col,sd,od),
    f,FILTER(so,NOT(ISERROR(sd))),
    r,IF(has_headers,VSTACK(TAKE(cd,1),f),f),
    r)
```

- Replace the bottom-most `r` with any of the other variables to get familiar with the 'ingredients' of the formula.

[image]